# How to free up miscalculating Storage on MacOS that occupies 90GB of my MacOS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, spotlight, storage

I have just reinstalled my MBP on Sonoma but I cannot install any software because of the insufficient storage error. However, the Storage setting shows I still have plenty of space but the Disk Utility says otherwise. Using Clean My Mac, only 24GB is scaned but the entire 121GB is used !!

[image]

These are my approaches but failed

- Spotlight re-indexing
- First-aid Disk Utilities
- Clearing Purgeable Space

Please help! This Macbook is old and I cannot afford to get it fixed (MPB 2019 Intel). Any recommendation helps. Thank you

Comment: If yours is old, mine must be an antique: MBP from 2016. :)

Comment: Your Disk Utility screenshot says you have less than 1gb space free on this drive.  That is detrimental to the proper operation of the OS, and you need to clear some space.  The remainder of the occupied space is in the -Data volume.

Answer (score 0):

In Disk Utility : View -> All Devices

Looks there is another Partition/Volume => Other Volumes